# Cannot ssh through jump host with ProxyCommand on Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy

My config file is as follows (I'm trying to directly `ssh` into foo):

```
Host foo
    HostName <ip>
    User <username>
    ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -q -W %h:%p jump

Host jump
    HostName <ip>
    User <username>
    ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -q -W %h:%p bar

Host bar
    HostName <ip>
    User <username>
    Port <num>
```

In addition, I have concatenated my `id_rsa.pub` key to `authorized_keys` of bar, jump and foo servers. When I run `ssh -J foo jump bar`, I get the error `CreateProcessW failed error:2 posix_spawn: No such file or directory`. When I try `ssh foo -v` I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for foo
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe -q -W <jump_ip> jump
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
```

Similarly, when I try `ssh jump -v`, I get

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/config line 12: Applying options for jump
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe -q -W <bar_ip:port_num> bar
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\CCL/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
```

The ssh process seems to be stuck and never authenticates nor does the key exchange. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's with the `ProxyCommand` lines?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use `bar` as a jump host to connect to `jump`, and use `jump` as a jump host to connect to `foo`.  In other words, trying to connect to `bar` like this:

```
local --> foo --> jump --> bar
```

Your ssh config should look like this:

```
Host foo
    HostName <ip>
    User <username>
    ProxyJump jump

Host jump
    HostName <ip>
    User <username>
    ProxyJump bar

Host bar
    HostName <ip>
    User <username>
    Port <num>
```

And then to connect, run just `ssh bar`.

`ProxyJump` is a simpler way to get what you want compared to `ProxyCommand`, assuming you're using OpenSSH 7.3 or newer.  Additionally, you don't need to use `-J` on the `ssh` command.  `-J` sets `ProxyJump` for the current invocation, which is unneeded if it's already in your config file.

Comment: It seems out of order on some points. The TCP connections go like these: `local --> bar --> jump --> foo`. "And then to connect, run just" I think needs `ssh foo`